# CSS Bootstrap 3.0 in Scheduled Emails CF

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, coldfusion

I am trying to create an automatic email that gets sent straight from the server. I am trying to have a bootstrap table appear in the email. Are you unable to use plugins for an email creation if you're still using HTML, or am I just doing something wrong? Anyone have any idea of how to make the bootstrap type table appear in an email?

```
<cfmail to="#sendTo#" from="#sendTo#" subject="Overdue Item" type="html">

<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/vendor/datatables/Bootstrap-3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<body>

 <h4>There is an overdue item in dealer work.</h4>

<p>
<cfif overdueTextArea.recordCount is 0>
There are no overdue items.
<cfelse>
<table>
    <thead>
        <th><b>ITEM ID</b></th>
        <th><b>DATE DUE</b></th>
        <th><b>QTY</b></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<cfloop query="overdueTextArea">
    <tr>
        <td>#id#</td>
        <td>#dateFormat(Date_Due, 'mm/dd/yyyy')#</td>
        <td>#Item_Count#</td>
    </tr>
</cfloop>
    </tbody>
</table>
</cfif>
</p>

</body>
</html>

</cfmail>
```

Comment: You can't really do this. CSS is already very restricted in some email clients, including css files is unlikely to work with most if not all email clients. You are best sticking to inline CSS in html emails.

Comment: well darn lol anyone know the inline css for bootstrap tables to be as close as possible?

Comment: Just look inside the bootstrap css for the table styles. There will still be some styles that are not supported as well so you might get it close but won't be exact and will probably look different depending on the email client.

Comment: how would u do a striped row though? like every other row striped?

Comment: Not really possible with CSS in this case. Although you could use CF to set a variable during your loop to the class name and use this variable on the table row.

Comment: @Vicki, it is a lot of CSS but it could be done. I would not be surprized if email programs strip out all CSS. If were creating a web email program, everything would run through `getSafeHTML()`

Comment: You don't need css to have striped rows.  The html tr tag has a bgcolor attribute.

Comment: Dan...join us in the 1990's. No one uses `bgcolor` anymore.

Comment: HTML based emails are tricky and many times reverts back to non-css techniques, like bgcolor on table rows, the font tag, and tables for layouts. And then you have to consider the dozens if not hundreds of email clients out there. Plus each web-based mail client does their own thing. Here is one fairly current article on the subject: http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-code-html-email-newsletters/.